# Powershell script in Task Scheduler - spaces and timestamp issue

Tags: powershell, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

following script works in Powershell, but won't work when executed as an action in Task Scheduler:

```
Copy-Item -Path '\\dfs.com\Risk Manage\Daily_DB\Daily_DB.accdb' -Destination "\\dfs.com\Risk Manage\SharedReports\Database Backup 2014\Daily_DB_backup $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).accdb"
```

Please note that I need to use double quotes in order to get $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd) translate into a timestamp. Doesn't work with single quotes.

Task Scheduler error message: *Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Manage\SharedReports\Database'.*

To sum it up, does anyone know how to execute Powershell script containing path with spaces and timestamp in it, in Task Scheduler?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could either call a script or use the `-encodedcommand` parameter: [Using Powershell -encodedcommand to pass parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295957/using-powershell-encodedcommand-to-pass-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Datestamp = (Get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
Copy-Item -Path '\\dfs.com\Risk Manage\Daily_DB\Daily_DB.accdb' -Destination "\\dfs.com\Risk Manage\SharedReports\Database Backup 2014\Daily_DB_backup_$Datestamp.accdb"
```