# How to write a FTP File Upload script using powershell in background in one line

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, upload, quote

Many methods using PowerShell exist to upload a file in a remote server.

I am using the `System.Net.WebClient` object to perform that task, and the `Start-Process` command to do this in background.

My goal is to perform that task using only a one line command, via `cmd.exe`.

The command below is used :

```
PowerShell.exe Start-Process -FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList "-c `"$uploadFile='PATH'; $linkFTP='ftp://user:pass@IP/file'; $client=New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient; $URI=New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftp; $client.UploadFile($URI,$uploadFile)`" "
```

This command ensures that via `cmd.exe`, you will perform a FTP file upload in background using PowerShell. Using a script file directly instead of using `-FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList "-c..."` will work, however with that method it will not.

You will notice if you run that command that it is certainly due to quotes problems.

Do you have any clue about it?

Thanks

Comment: If you are having issues with quoting then using `-EncodedCommand` would be a great approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295957/using-powershell-encodedcommand-to-pass-parameters

Comment: Nice approach, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-Process -FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList "-c {$uploadFile='PATH'; $linkFTP='ftp://user:pass@IP/file'; $client=New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient; $URI=New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftp; $client.UploadFile($URI,$uploadFile)} "
```

Edit:

Note:`$ftp` variable is not defined

Comment: You use square brackets to try to solve the problem. However, I tried with your solution but an error occured telling that an argument is missing for ArgumentList

Comment: your `$ftp` variable is not defined anywhere, so `-ArgumentList` for `New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList`  will be null.